# Is sql injection and cross-site scripting still a thing?

Tags: xss, sql-injection

When looking up some information about web attacks, sql injection and cross-site scripting are always on the table. I can't imagine that such old web attack where there is a lot of information to find on the internet about how to prevent against it is still in the top 10 of most used web attacks? Any explaination for this?

Comment: I think this is more of a stackexchange question then a stack overflow question, I would vote for closing

Comment: @LucaBruzzone, Stack Overflow requires questions about coding that have an unambiguously correct answer, right? The answer to this question is clearly, "yes, these security vulnerabilities are still a thing."

Comment: ok, makes sense. Ah no, I just saw that it was actually closed for opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll tell a story.

My mother used to volunteer with a group to go to the local college campus to help students register to vote (in the US, people can vote at age 18, but they aren't registered by default, they have to fill out a form). She and her group would set up a table in the quad with a supply of forms and guide the students to fill it out and mail it in.

After years of doing this, one of the other women in the group said, "We've been coming onto campus to help these kids register for TEN YEARS! When are they going to be able to do it on their own?"

My mom and the others looked at her and said slowly, "There is a new set of students turning 18 years old every year."

The same thing is true for defense against SQL injection and Cross-Site Scripting. There are new programmers entering the profession every year.

In fact, studies show that the number of software developers doubles every five years, which means at any given time, 50% of software developers are what I would consider "junior developers" with less than five years of experience. By the time those people have become senior developers, there's again just as many younger developers who have entered the profession after them.

All of them need to be trained to understand SQL injection and Cross-Site Scripting defense before they should be allowed to put their code on a live server.

One at a time.

Every year.

SQL injection and Cross-Site scripting will continue to be a thing as long as there are software developers.

---

I also can reference the [SQLi Hall-of-Shame](https://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/), a web page that references news stories about data breaches perpetrated by exploiting SQL injection vulnerabilities. The seem to be multiple such stories every month, and these are just the break-ins that made the news. It's undoubtedly the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 2):

The quantity and the quality are two different beasts. "A lot of information" doesn't mean helpful information. On the contrary, there are many contradicting, open-ended and ambiguous recommendations.

For example, up to this day OWASP lists ["Escaping All User-Supplied Input"](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#defense-option-4-escaping-all-user-supplied-input) as a *Primary*(sic!) defense. Which, frankly, a [nonsense](https://phpdelusions.net/top#escaping_user_input)

Another example is a decades-old superstition that sounds as "escaping prevents SQL injections".

Given a lot of such misleading or open-ended recommendations, such us "always *validate* the user input" (without a single hint on which *particular* validation is meant) a junior dev gets extremely confused, and let an injection in.